# paypal credentials incorrect outside Api explorer

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

I have troubles getting this code working. It keeps returning "API credentials are incorrect" but in Paypal API Explorer using the same credentials it works!

```
    $headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "****",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "****",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "****",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" => "APP-80W284485P519543T",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS" => "****",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE" => "merchant-php-sdk-2.0.96"
);

$data = array(
    'emailAddress' => 'Anonimandro-buyer@gmail.com',
    'matchCriteria' => 'NONE'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

print_r( $response );
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

headers array fed to curl call was incorrect. It should be:

```
$headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ****",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ****",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ****",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: ****",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE: merchant-php-sdk-2.0.96"
);
```